# Pass foreign key from controller to model for specific query cakephp 2.3.9

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-model, cakephp-2.3

I want to use two different foreign key for two different query

For my first query I want like:

my model code is like

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Emailformatstype' => array(
        'className' => 'Emailformatstype',
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
    )
);
```

now for my second query I want like:

my model code is like

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Emailformatstype' => array(
        'className' => 'Emailformatstype',
        'foreignKey' => 'New_id'
    )
);
```

So my question is is there any technique so I can pass foreignKey from controller for specific query

something like as we provide recursive

```
$this->Model->recursive = 0;
```

same I want like:

```
$this->Model->foreignKey= 'My_foreignKey';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply access the associations property:

```
$this->Model->belongsTo['YourAssoc']['foreignKey'] = 'my_foreignKey';
```

Some best practice: Emailformatstype is a bad name, this should be EmailFormatType. Reads better and matches the convention. Notice the plural you had before (formats) which would make it a join table by convention.

Comment: thanks for your answer,and about model name I have just used dummy text

Comment: in this case no need to specify association in model, but if I am specifying any then which association will apply? one which I specify in controller or model once ?

Comment: OOP basics: It's an instance. As long as you don't get a new instance of the model it does not matter where (model or a model method for that like changeAssoNameFK() for example is better than controller) as long as you set it before you need it and set it back when you don't need the changed FK anymore.